# Insert into MySQL table from value and select statement

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to insert values into one table by selecting fields from another table and also add information such date and login_id (these do not come from the table where I am selecting).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions_to_answer (login_id, question_id, Question_Category, QuestionType, Question, Meaning) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt= $DB_con->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute($test_user_id, 
    "SELECT question_id, 
            Question_Category, 
            QuestionType, 
            Question, 
            Meaning all_questions 
      WHERE personality_profile_questions.Question_Category = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `SELECT` in the `prepare`, you can't have SQL commands in the execute. If in the execute it will be treated as a literal string, quoted, and escaped.

Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions_to_answer (login_id, question_id, Question_Category, QuestionType, Question, Meaning) 
        SELECT ?, question_id, Question_Category, QuestionType, Question, Meaning 
        WHERE personality_profile_questions.Question_Category = 1";
$stmt= $DB_con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($test_user_id));
```

Assuming `$test_user_id` = `login_id`. I'm not clear what `all_questions` is.